# How to serialize my model to get desired output

Tags: python, django, serialization

I want to serialize my model which having multiple object. I want to nest them.

this is my model

```
class model8():
   country = foreign key
   a_image = "ImageField"
   b_image = "ImageFiled" 
   a_url = char filed
   b_url = char filed
```

and my desired output is

```
  {
 “ a_images”:[
   {
        “image”: “”,
        “url”: “”
   },
   {
       “image”: “”,
        “url”: “”
   }
],
“b_images”:[
   {
      “image”: “”,
      “url”: “”
   },
  {
      “image”: “”,
      “url”: “”
   }
 ]
}
```

can any one help solve this huddle

Comment: what problem did you face?

Comment: While serializing i am not getting the desired output like this. I am a beginner i don't know how to achive this please help

Comment: please add your code and error

Comment: Sorry i dont know how to do that. Please help to how achive this

Comment: you can edit the question and add details

Answer (score 1):

You need to define serializers as below and learn about SerializerMethodField.

```
class imageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    a_images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    b_images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = model8
        fields = ('__all__')
    def get_a_images (self, instance):
        return (model8.objects.values_list('a_image ', 'a_url'))
    def get_b_images (self, instance):
        return (model8.objects.values_list('b_image ', 'b_url'))
```

Set values of the field "FIELDS" as you need.

Comment: I recognized this is not the accurate answer for what you are looking. Anyhow this may help.

Comment: This shows an error values_list() is not json serializable

Comment: Well, You can learn more about how to select multiple fields in queryset.